# Uniqueness of diagonalisation of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric with diagonalisation $A = P\Lambda P^{T}$, where $P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is unitary and $\Lambda = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n) $, where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of A.

My question is, is such a diagonalisation unique? In particular, are diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ necessarily the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $Λ=P^{-1}AP$ (i.e. its diagonal entries) are necessarily the same as those of $A$, like in any diagonalization. As for the first question: the diagonalisation is "essentially" unique, also like the diagonalization of any (diagonalizable) matrix. This "essentially" stands just to take into account the permutation of the eigenvectors (and associated eigenvalues), as well, when an eigenspace is of dimension $>1$, the change of base of that eigenspace.